# how to update django auth_user with queryset?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I use username='admin' and password='hash' i will update auth_user with ID table

```
UsermodelUpdate= User.objects.filter(id=RSAEnrcyption().decrypt_RSA(request.session['privateKEY'],GetID)).update(username='ramin')
UsermodelUpdate.set_password(getPassWordUI)
UsermodelUpdate.save()
```

i get error :

```
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'ramin' for key 'username'")
```

Comment: It seems that you already have this username. Try by any other name. Username is unique field. You cannot have same username for two different users.

Comment: Now i able update username but no password,how to update password filed hash for update table auth_user?

Comment: see answer below. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using filter which is used to fetch multiple records. As you are filtering using id, You will get unique record. You can do this like this

```
UsermodelUpdate= User.objects.get(id=RSAEnrcyption().decrypt_RSA(request.session['privateKEY'],GetID))
UsermodelUpdate.username = 'unique_username'
UsermodelUpdate.set_password(getPassWordUI)
UsermodelUpdate.save()
```

But if you want to perform this function for multiple records, you can do this like this

```
UsermodelUpdate= User.objects.filter(id=RSAEnrcyption().decrypt_RSA(request.session['privateKEY'],GetID)).update(username='unique_username')
for user in UsermodelUpdate:
    user.set_password(getPassWordUI)
    user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, underestand,

Answer (score 0):

```
UsermodelUpdate.set_password(GetPassWordUI())
```

Comment: what your means "GetPassWordUI()"? this is not function

Comment: What is the model default value? is it a callable?

Comment: is not callable,i just update username ( .update(username='ramin') ), but i get error "IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'ramin' for key 'username'")"

Comment: Got you. Duplicate entry means that the value is not unique. It happens when you provide a wrong default, since defaults are evaluated once for the entire model. Post your model file?